JdbcTemplate throws Table or view doesn't exist if WHERE clause in UPDATE statement doesn't find any results
I have a simple UPDATE statement like so:
UPDATE SCHEMA.TABLE SET STATE = 'ACTIVE' WHERE STATE = 'INACTIVE'

In SQL Developer this works all the time, even if there aren't any records with 'INACTIVE' status, returning '0 rows updated' in such case.
However, when executing the same query with jdbcTemplate.update(query) or jdbcTemplate.execute(query), it only works if there are any records with 'INACTIVE' status at the time of execution. Otherwise, if there aren't any 'INACTIVE' records, I get:
class org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE SCHEMA.TABLE SET STATE = 'ACTIVE' WHERE STATE = 'INACTIVE']; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
I want the query to execute regardless there are any records with 'INACTIVE' status, but I don't know what I'm missing/what to do to achieve this.
Thank you in advance!

"UPDATE TABLE.COLUMN" is interpreted as "UPDATE SCHEMA.TABLE", so if you get an error from Spring app it just means your are connecting with a user not having access to the schema you named "TABLE" (if even exists...).

TABLE.COLUMN was actually a typo, I corrected it. I'm using SCHEMA.TABLE indeed. If it were the case of connecting with a user not having access to the schema, then why does the update execute without issues when in the SCHEMA.TABLE there is at least one record whose STATE column's value is 'INACTIVE'?

I would write a simple Java class that performs the [SQL] UPDATE using pure JDBC, i.e. without the Spring framework and see if you get the same error.

Issue resolved, can check my comment under Jens Schauder's answer.


I want the query to execute regardless there are any records with 'INACTIVE' status, but I don't know what I'm missing/what to do to achieve this.

Your query does just that.
But the table SCHEMA.TABLE does not exist or is not accessible by the db user executing that statement.
There are actually a bunch of somewhat more involved scenarios where you get this exception. See SQL Error: ORA-00942 table or view does not exist

You are correct. After your affirmation that the query does just that, I checked and even though the table did exist and the user had the privileges, I realized I was connecting to the wrong schema by mistake. I'm gonna go hide under a rock now. Thanks for the quick reply, much appreciated!
